# @Solana/Web3.js is not working properly on Android React Native

Tags: web3.js, react-native

Trying integrating Solana into React Native, but the Android app seems to be not working properly

The following transaction supposes to send 0.1 SOL, but it eventually send way less than that on Android.
The same code (same implementation, same params) works fine on iOS though. On iOS it sends exact 0.1 SOL.

https://explorer.solana.com/tx/k4t3MGyecTqmA3nyKtyDubQ1brW1LnHV3MWAvNArB88k1bYX4wYW4H9ab4Dh75P1Egf25YrKzUrpqqX3dkXLRNm?cluster=devnet

Any idea guys?

The packages that I currently use

`React Native: 0.67.5`

`@Solana/web3.js: 1.41.6`

Comment: share iOS transaction id as well as where it is working correctly.

Comment: Here is the transaction on iOS
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5i9dz2Wh8mZetq4zywssppLoDwxb1XsiTbkQLPhSgZiytRZmYj9CJ7vJZRsnJT6Q8jhkMDEA4CnNQztBdqhSMnzM?cluster=devnet


Another Android transaction, just tested
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/66nza6XQKgqUrxkdZfdaYoufpAd6wsqKL8e4sDyfis1mUGRUgJjUFhBBFeQaUJKcnJL8jNaSoTPHEuL8fX2RPkNc?cluster=devnet


You can find the implementation here, I used the same one for both iOS and Android: https://pastecode.io/s/0kdup0s7

Comment: @AbdullahQureshi hello, any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add my own solution here

The JS engine I use is `jsc-android@250230.2.1` which does not have `BigInt` supports. Upgrade to `jsc-android@294992.0.0` solves the issue.

More details can be found here: https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts/issues/159